# can't get subscribers with fql query

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Is there a way to extract the subscribers of a user profile with FQL query ?

the classic method works $fb->api("/subscribers") when the user is loggend in on the aplication and facebook
...but because of some facebook settings (that only some user have), even if I have full access token the application can't extract friends and subscribers  via   $fb->api("/....") when they are offline. (and with the same token I can extract friends with query "SELECT uid2  FROM friend WHERE uid1 = xxx limit 0,5000")

The error that facebook throws is ">(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 0 "

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the subscription table

`SELECT subscriber_id FROM subscription WHERE subscribed_id = me()`